# Can I visit UK for a couple of days on a national visa for Poland?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, poland

I have a national visa for Poland as I'm studying here.

Can I visit UK for a couple of days on the same visa?

Comment: What exact visa do you have? And what's your nationality?

Comment: @Gagravarr could the answer to either of your questions change the answer to the original question?

Answer (score 6):

**No,** visas for the Schengen countries give no right relevant to entering the UK. If your nationality is one that needs visas to enter the UK, having a Schengen visa does not change that.